# How to remove anything that looks like a date

Tags: excel

I have data that is very poorly entered when the data set was created.

**Context:**

A particular cell has some date, letters, and a number or some random stuff.  The information that I want to extract looks like "xxxxxIB" a five digit number followed by the letters "IB". But frequently this type of entry isn't  there, the "IB" isn't there and all kinds of other stuff is there.

**For this question:**

Sometimes a date appears in various formats that I want to delete from the cell.  Just to simplify my life, for starters.

A typical cell could appear in any of the below formats. The stuff in **\ are my comments:

```
      A1
ALM 03/09/2014 45099IB  \* mm/dd/yyy format *\
ALM45099IB 03092014     \* mmddyyyy *\
ALM111-3/09/2014         \*m\dd\yyyy *\
45099IB_30914            \* mmdyy *\
45099IB-030914            \* mmddyy *\
ALM_30914                 \* mddyy *\
alm5 03914 
alm6 031114                \*wrong date entered *\
03092014alm_1              \* date first then other stuff *\
223LA                      \* No date at all *\
alm 0309214                \* writing year 2014 as 214 *\
```

So my data sometimes has no date, sometimes the wrong date appears, and sometimes the right date appears but it could be in one of many many formats and in all imaginable combinations with other data.

My data has a date column so I know what date is going to appear (unless they typed the wrong date in). Right now I have written eight different SUBSTITUTE commands to replace some formats of dates with blanks.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy"),"")
```

It obviously doesn't work when the data entry process entered the date incorrectly or written the date weirdly. Is there a clever way to get excel to read all date-like objects and delete them?

Link to Full data: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvFuTVHLZcVoX__szeQsChItjC51VhbnmLkr8-c2apc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: How about saving it as a csv file and do some sed or awk scripting?

Comment: @stakSmashr I don't know what that is, but the first google search link I opened seems very promising. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Fiddle that works with most of your data:

**http://jsfiddle.net/w97hw10y/5/**

(Tested in Chrome.)

1. Paste your data in the **HTML** box.  (It defaults to the data in your post.)
2. Click **Run**.
3. Copy/paste from the **Result** box into Excel.

This was written in JavaScript and jQuery.  Here's the source:

```
$('body').text($('body').text().trim());
var data= $('body').text().split('\n');
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
  var d= data[i].split(/[ \-_]/g);
  for(var j = 0 ; j < d.length ; j++) {
    var val= d[j];
    if($.isNumeric(val)) {
      if(val.length===8) {
        val= val.substr(0,2)+'/'+val.substr(2,2)+'/'+val.substr(4);
      }
      else if(val.length===6) {
        val= val.substr(0,2)+'/'+val.substr(2,2)+'/20'+val.substr(4);
      }
      else if(val.length===5) {
        val= val.substr(0,1)+'/'+val.substr(1,2)+'/20'+val.substr(3);
        var dt= new Date(val);
        if(dt.toString()==='Invalid Date') {
          val= d[j];
          val= val.substr(0,2)+'/'+val.substr(2,1)+'/20'+val.substr(3);
          var dt= new Date(val);
          if(dt.toString()==='Invalid Date') continue;
        }
      }
      else continue;
    }
    var dt= new Date(val);
    if(dt.toString()!=='Invalid Date') {
      data[i]= data[i].replace(d[j],'') + '<td> '+dt.toLocaleDateString();
    }
  }
}

$('body').html('<table><tr><td>'+data.join('<tr><td>')+'</table>');
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you. That works for 95% of my data. Very cool!! Thank you!!

Comment: Sure thing.  If there are recognizable patterns in your other 5% of data, I may be able to program them as well.  I'll just need some examples to work with.

Comment: Thanks! I've included a link to the data. It contains two columns. The first one contains the date from which I want to remove date like objects. The second column contains the actual date that should be there but may not always be because of data entry errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/w97hw10y/21/.  Your data is in the HTML box, and output is in the Result box.  If the date in column two is found in column one, it's removed and column two is highlighted green.  If something in column one looks like a date, but it doesn't match column two, it's moved to column three and is highlighted pink.  Hopefully this gets close to 100%.